# Why this three SQL cost different?

Tags: mysql, sql

I created a user_bill_cp table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `user_bill_cp` (
  `id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'ID',
  `gmt_create` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP COMMENT 'gmt_create',
  `gmt_modified` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP COMMENT 'gmt_modified',
  `user_id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'user ID',
  `bill_no` varchar(50) NOT NULL COMMENT 'bill no',
  `money` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL COMMENT 'money',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `idx_user_id` (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=10001001 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci COMMENT='user bill'
```

then create a user_id index like this:

```
+--------------+------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+------------+
| Table        | Non_unique | Key_name    | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment | Visible | Expression |
+--------------+------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+------------+
| user_bill_cp |          0 | PRIMARY     |            1 | id          | A         |     9713675 |     NULL |   NULL |      | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
| user_bill_cp |          1 | idx_user_id |            1 | user_id     | A         |           1 |     NULL |   NULL |      | BTREE      |         |               | YES     | NULL       |
+--------------+------------+-------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+---------+------------+
```

I insert 10 millions rows randomly into this table with the same user_id=77820;

```
mysql> select count(id) from user_bill_cp where user_id=77820;
+-----------+
| count(id) |
+-----------+
|  10001000 |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.99 sec)
```

I want to know why these SQLs below cost different in method 1 vs method 2?

**Method 1**

execute SQL:

```
select * 
from user_bill_cp 
where id in ( 
    select a.id 
    from (
        select id 
        from user_bill_cp 
        where user_id=77820 order by id asc limit 20 offset 5000000
        ) a
    );
```

cost 4.27sec;

**Method 2**

execute SQL:

```
select a.id 
from (
    select id 
    from user_bill_cp 
    where user_id=77820 order by id asc limit 20 offset 5000000
    ) a;
```

cost 0.69sec

execute SQL:

```
select * 
from user_bill_cp 
where id in (5000001 ,5000002,5000003,5000004,5000005,5000006,5000007,5000008,5000009,5000010,5000011,5000012,5000013,5000014,5000015,5000016,5000017,5000018,5000019,5000020);
```

cost 0.01 sec

My question:

why the time cost so different between the method 1 vs method 2 ? （4.27 sec > 0.69 sec + 0.01 sec）

if you know how, please tell me. thank you very much!!!

I also try this like this：

```
select * 
from user_bill_cp 
where id in ( 
    select a.id 
    from (
        select id 
        from user_bill_cp 
        where user_id=77820 limit 1 offset 5000000
        ) a
    );
```

```
select * 
from user_bill_cp 
where id in ( 
    select a.id 
    from (
        select id 
        from user_bill_cp 
        where user_id=77820 limit 200 offset 5000000
        ) a
    );
```

limit 1 and limit 200 almost cost the same.

I expected the SQL:

```
select * 
from user_bill_cp 
where id in (
    select a.id 
    from (
        select id 
        from user_bill_cp 
        where user_id=77820 limit 20 offset 5000000
        ) a
    );
```

cost the same time with the sum of this two SQLs below:

1:

```
select a.id 
from (
    select id 
    from user_bill_cp 
    where user_id=77820 limit 20 offset 5000000
    ) a;
```

2:

```
select * 
from user_bill_cp 
where id in (5000001 ,5000002,5000003,5000004,5000005,5000006,5000007,5000008,5000009,5000010,5000011,5000012,5000013,5000014,5000015,5000016,5000017,5000018,5000019,5000020);
```

Comment: See also [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952)

Comment: well, a subquery in a WHERE isn't guaranteed to run only once. If it referenced anything in the table being queried, it would need to run for every row. In this exact case, it should optimize it, but you might be running into caching that improves result on your second test.

Comment: If you haven't already, reviewing the actual execution plan for these queries might provide some insight into time differences.

Comment: `LIMIT`-ing without `ORDER`-ing rarely makes sense. Fix those queries first, before we can look at their performance.

Comment: @GarrGodfrey  I try to change the limit numbers in the subquery, I found that limit 1 cost almost the same with limit 200

Comment: @TheImpaler I fix it with ORDER-ing , the result is the same with before

Comment: Please provide us with the [query plan](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/execution-plan-information.html) for each statement, and your version of MySQL.

Comment: One is doing `select *` and one is only selecting the ID. If you only select the ID it can do an "index-only scan" where it reads the ID directly from the ID index and never looks at the table. `select *` must read the table possibly slowing it down. Try having both only select the id. See [covering index](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/glossary.html#glos_covering_index).

Comment: Thanks for replacing the images, please now read and action the _other_ meta link (3rd time lucky!) and as asked a few times add the explain output to the question.

Comment: The answer is closed so I can't answer, but [here you are](https://gist.github.com/schwern/ec08e6c93162fe8fab137380d73abe91). The nested subquery in Method 1 is materialized (writes the results to a temp table) which slows it down. Method 2 is optimized to eliminate the unnecessary subquery; it is equivalent to `select id from user_bill_cp where user_id=77820 order by id asc limit 20 offset 5000000;`. As suspected, `select id` can do an index-only scan which improves performance considerably.